# Handling dynamic tables in selenium web driver using Xpath

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium

i am using selenium web driver for the test automation work for a web site. In that web site there is a page where it display details of a purchase order. It has multiple tables with no id/name associated with them. The design is using just "td" and "tr" elements. Each table can contain multiple rows,columns depending on the purchase order. I want to validate each and every field with given values. How can i get these dynamic details using Xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the total number of `<tr>` tags within a `<td>` tag by giving the xpath of the `<td>` element by using this [function](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) -

```
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Xpath of the table"));
```

Now you can use a for each loop to loop through each of the `<tr>` tags in the above list and then read each value by using [getText()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29) method.

Let me know if this helps you.